# Detail formatter error: Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files

I'm getting the following error while I'm in debug mode:

Detail formatter error:
Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements

Code Example:

```
   try {
        content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] parts = content.split("."); //Here I get the above error
```

Am I doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
String[] parts = content.split("\\.");
```

Comment: weird. content.split(".") is a valid expression. Don't know why you got that error. Did you clean your project?